# ZendFramework function init() not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2

my code...................:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function init()
    {
       echo 'init worked';
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

why the init function is not working? maybe i need to change some configs? or I need to use the standart php __construct() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ZF2 is safe to use the constructor `__construct()` so the old  `init()` method has been removed.

http://www.mwop.net/blog/2012-07-30-the-new-init.html

Answer (score 1):

This changed in ZF2. If you want to accomplish the same thing either do it in the constructor of your controller (__construct()) or if you need to do a lot of fancy stuff you should create a Factory for your controller and define it in the module config.

```
 'controllers' => array(
     'factories' => array(
          'TestController' => 'Your\Namespace\TestControllerFactory'
     )
 )
```

The TestControllerFactory should implement the Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface, which means it should implement the createService method.

Comment: Remark that factories are only necessary for inject dependencies to controllersm without that need `invokables` is more simple

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom initializer to make the `init()` method work:

```
// in your Module class
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $cl = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('ControllerLoader');

    $cl->addInitializer(function ($controller, $serviceManager) {
        if (method_exists($controller, 'init')) {
            $controller->init();
        }
    }, false); // false means the initializer will be added in the bottom of the stack
}
```

Adding the initializer at the bottom of the stack is good because the built in initializers will be called first, so you will have access to `ServiceLocator` and `EventManager` in the `init()` method.